# Usage of word 'than' for comparison

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Is this correct if I say,

> I like everything else than winters.

instead of,

> I don't like winters.

if I want to exaggerate the dislike for winters.

I have read that "than" can be used after adjectives or adverbs but in this sentence there is a pronoun I think.

Comment: You should be more precise and say "than" is used after comparatives and else is no comparative.

Comment: @rogermue Din't get you. Please explain.. (I may be wrong in this sentence also. May be :P )

Answer (score 3):

Even though the sentence is technically correct, I think the correct sentence should be,

> I like everything else other than winters.

It expresses your distaste for "winters" and I've observed in many instances people using the above way to express their distastes.

Comment: As a footnote, usually _winters_ would be not capitalized (unless we are talking about a person with that last name). An exception might be found in poetic contexts. [More here](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/capitalization-of-seasons.html). Also, the _else_ could be omitted: _I like everything other than Winters._

Answer (score 1):

To emphasize your dislike for winters, I'd rather use

> I like anything **but** winters.

"Everything else than" does not seem idiomatic to me.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I know about this but i just wanted to know if I can use it like that or not.

Answer (score 0):

'Except' is the perfect word to use for this. Also, I suggest that you ditch the s on winter. What you dislike is the state of winter, rather than a particular number of winters.

```
I like everything except winter
```

Comment: Winter comes every year.. And it is not just for one year, dislike is for every year.. That's why I used **winters**. Like if I don't like a cake I would say I don't like **cakes** if I dislike each and every cake. Correct me if I am wrong. @Javababe

Comment: For one cake, you use either a determinant (the, a) or a demonstrative adjective (this,that), for example "I don't like **this** cake". For cake in general, it's uncountable, which covers everything from a tiny crumb of cake to all the cakes in the world. For uncountables you use the singular form without determinant or demonstrative- "I don't like cake". Going back to winter, you should only use the uncountable,  unless you want to talk about specific ones, eg "the last five winters".

Comment: I still think it would be **I don't like cakes** .  I don't know much about usage rules but **cakes** sound correct while **cake** don't @Javababe.

Comment: Cake vs cakes is debatable: you could say either, though the majority of native English speakers would use the uncountable (cake) if they don't like cake in general. With winter, though, practically all native English speakers would say "I don't like winter", meaning they don't like the state (uncountable) rather than any particular winters.