# Winters or winter

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, singular-vs-plural

In my question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83385/usage-of-word-than-for-comparison), I have used a sentence

> I don't like winters.

While a user commented that I should use **winter** and not **winters**. But from my understanding, winter comes every year and disliking winter is for every year,not just for one year. So it should be **winters**.
Which one is correct?

EDIT: 
 
 I found it [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/winter-or-winters.1977276/) that winter can be singular or plural depending on the sentence construction. And the sentence in this question, I think it would be **winters** itself.

Comment: It would be singular when referring to seasons, unless a quantity is specified, like "It snowed two *winters* ago.". In your example, you might think of it like "I don't like *wintertime*."

Comment: Lets say I have been asked a question- Which season you don't like then I would say I don't like winters.. neither winter time nor winter. Right? @user3169

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the sentence,

> I don't like winters.

**winters** refers to the season in plural, describing a dislike for a quantity of winters.  This adds ambiguity to the sentence as the range or amount of "disliked winters" is unspecified.

Changing **winters** to **winter** would imply a *dislike for winter in general*.  This greatly clarifies the meaning of the sentence:

> I don't like winter.

Comment: *A dislike for a group of winters*.Could you kindly describe the situation?